# Lengths of curves and metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to digest page-59 of Pavel Grinfeld's tensor calculus book, the quick rundown of what's going on in the page is this: Suppose we endow the flat euclidean plane with some coordinates $(Z_1,Z_2,Z_3)$ and consider motion of a particle along a coordinate line given by the function:

$$P(t) = (Z_1^o + t ,Z_2^0 , Z_3^0)$$

Then the length of the coordinate curve as traversed by the particle is given as::

$$L_{11}(t) = \int_0^t \sqrt{Z_{11} (h) } dh$$

Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$L_{11}' = \sqrt{Z_{11}}$$

It is said that we can evaluate the metric tensor entries using the above relation, but I don't understand, how do we find $L_{11}'$ without the metric tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One paragraph before, he says

> Suppose
> also, that the only measurement you are allowed to take is the length of any curve
> segment. From equation (5.20), it follows that this would allow you to calculate the
> metric tensor at any point. Thus, lengths of curves can be calculated from the metric
> tensor and vice versa. ..."

So he's assuming you can calculate $L_{11}(t)$ (may be with a ruler, I guess?) for every $t$, which allows you to calculate $L'_{11}(t)$.
It's a thought experiment.

Comment: Misto sheaf! I had glanced through this, but thought maybe I was missing something deep and hence asked. Thanks for clarifying as always :D